# Как присвоить переменной класс?

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть код который автоматически определяет высоту селекта в зависимости от того сколько там пунктов

```
<select multiple='multiple' id='select' style='overflow:hidden'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>

<script>
    var select = document.getElementById('select-filter');
    select.size = select.length;
</script>
```

Вопрос как мне присвоить в качестве значение переменой select не id  класс.

```
var select = document.getelementsbyclassname('select-filter');
```

.getelementsbyclassname не работает.

Comment: `.getelementsbyclassname` не работает. - потому что такой функции нет

Comment: `select = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('.myclass'),
    option = select.querySelectorAll('option');

select.size = option.length;
```

```html
<select multiple='multiple' class='myclass' style='overflow:hidden'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
```

Или так:

```js
var select = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0],
    option = select.getElementsByTagName('option');

select.size = option.length;
```

```html
<select multiple='multiple' class='myclass' style='overflow:hidden'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за варианты!
можно чуть укортить

var select = document.querySelector('.myclass');
select.size = select.length;